# Variable shows undefined in Angular9

Tags: angular, angular-services, ionic5

I am new to Angular 9 and hence running into problems. I am using ionic 5 + Angular 9 A variable shows as undefined when I am trying to console.log it. The description is bit long, please bear with me.

To start with, I have the following rest response:

```
{
"level_labels": [
    "Chapter",
    "Shloka"
],
"total_first_level_terms": 18,
}
```

I want to push the values of the keys into an array, so that my array looks like `[["Chapter","Sloka"],18]`

I have made a service named heritage-texts.service, and the following function extracts the values of the keys from the response above:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
   import { HeritageText } from './heritage-texts.model';

    @Injectable({
        providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class HeritageTextsService {

    toc = [];



   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getTOCHeritageText(heritageId : string) {

      this.fetchTOC(heritageId).subscribe(response => {


      for(const key in response){
        if( response.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
           this.toc.push(response[key]);
     }

   }

     console.log(this.toc});
  });
  return this.toc;
 }
 }
```

console.log(toc) shows the array as desired when the function is called. 
This is the page where I am trying to console.log the variable on ngOnInit():

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { HeritageText } from '../heritage-texts.model';
    import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    import { HeritageTextsService } from '../heritage-texts.service';

   @Component({
     selector: 'app-heritage-text-detail',
     templateUrl: './heritage-text-detail.page.html',
     styleUrls: ['./heritage-text-detail.page.scss'],
     })
   export class HeritageTextDetailPage implements OnInit {

  loadedHeritagetextTOC;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private heritageTextsService: HeritageTextsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
      if(!paramMap.has('heritageId')) {
        return;
      }
      const heritageId = paramMap.get('heritageId');

      this.loadedHeritagetextTOC = this.heritageTextsService.getTOCHeritageText(heritageId);
      console.log(this.loadedHeritagetextTOC);

    });

  }


}
```

console.log(this.loadedHeritagetextTOC) shows undefined.

Comment: It appears you're new to Angular. In that case try to go through [this](https://angular.io/tutorial) tutorial. It introduces some of the basic concepts. More info on accessing asynchronous data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/6513921).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're dealing with asynchronous observables (an HTTP request), you should return it and subscribe to it just in your component.

### Your service:

```js
getTOCHeritageText(heritageId: string): Observable<any> {
 return this.fetchTOC(heritageId);
}
```

### Your component:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
    // get your parameter value
    map(paramMap => paramMap.get('heritageId')),

    // switch it to a new observable, according to heritageId value
    switchMap((heritageId: string | undefined | null) => herigateId 
      ? this.heritageTextsService.getTOCHeritageText(heritageId)
      : of({}))
  ).subscribe((response: any) => 
      this.loadedHeritagetextTOC = Object.values(response));

}
```

Comment: This works. But this.loadedHeritagetextTOC = Object.values(response)); does it return an array?

Comment: Yeah, an array with the values. It's a shortcut for `Object.keys(response).map(key => response[key])`